# An inequality about expectation

Tags: expected-value, probability-inequalities, martingale

If $X_n$ is a *martingales* with $sup E|X_n|^p<\infty$ where $p>1$, How can show that
$$E^p|X_n|\leq E |X_n|^p$$

Comment: The martingale property is irrelevant.  This is a standard application of Holder's inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality.

Comment: Yes, this is a Holder's inequality with $Y=1$ and $q=\dfrac{p}{p-1}$. thanks @dsaxton

Comment: Taking the pth root of both sides reduces this to the duplicate question (assuming a generous interpretation of the notation, which is ambiguous).